# How should systematic uncertainties (up and down) in training data be handled in classification neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification, uncertainty

I have a classification neural network and nominal input data on which it is trained, however the input data has for each feature a systematic (up and down) uncertainty. How should the accuracy of the classifier be qualified and visualised using these input data uncertainties? I have a simple MWE example composed using the iris dataset; the intention is that is should be copy-pastable easily into a Jupyter notebook.

Lotsa imports:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import activations
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate, Conv1D, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model, Sequential, load_model
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter, NullLocator, MultipleLocator
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import auc, roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from vis.utils import utils
from vis.visualization import visualize_activation
from vis.visualization import visualize_saliency
import datetime
import keras
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import talos as ta
sns.set_palette('husl')
sns.set(style='ticks')
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]
```

Let's load the iris dataset and limit it to two classes, then prepare it for training.

```
iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data    = np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
    columns = iris['feature_names'] + ['target']
)
df = df.query('target != 2')
df.head()

df['labels'] = df['target'].astype('category').cat.codes
x = df[['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']]
y = df['target']
# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices using 1 hot encoding.
# 0 ---> 1, 0, 0
# 1 ---> 0, 1, 0
# 2 ---> 0, 0, 1
num_classes = len(y.unique())
y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, len(y.unique()))

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)

x = x.reshape(len(x), 4, 1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.33, shuffle = True)
```

Let's make some simple model for classification.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_shape = (4, 1),         activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.7))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5,                               activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,                     activation = 'softmax', name = 'preds'))
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer  = "nadam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

Now for a quick bit of training...

```
%%time
def model_evaluation(model, x_test, y_test, verbose=False):
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=verbose)
    print('max. test accuracy observed:', max(model.history.history['val_acc']))
    print('max. test accuracy history index:', model.history.history['val_acc'].index(max(model.history.history['val_acc'])))
    plt.plot(model.history.history['acc'])
    plt.plot(model.history.history['val_acc'])
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train_accuracy', 'test_accuracy'], loc='best')
    plt.show()
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size      = 2,
    epochs          = 100,
    verbose         = False,
    validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
)
model_evaluation(model, x_test, y_test, verbose=False)
```

Now, let's add some uncertainties for each of the features:

```
for column in ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']:
    uncertainties_up   = 0.1 * df[column].mean() * np.random.random_sample(size=(len(df)))
    uncertainties_down = df[column].mean() * np.random.random_sample(size=(len(df)))
    df[column + " uncertainty up"] = df[column] + uncertainties_up
df.head()
```

*And now* what actually comes next, in order to qualify the classifier given these various input data uncertainties?

Comment: I think this is a great question. It is unclear to me whether you are thinking of the question from a probabilistic perspective or not. I believe that the non-bayesian view point is that the dataset contains noise and that one should regularise the model in order to prevent overfitting. With a variety of techniques: the most important among them to evaluate the loss against a validation set. For instance your model contains a Dropout node (with high probability) which serves to regularise the model.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. If I understand u correct, ur goal is to handle aleatoric (data inherent) uncertainty in a classification setting.

One option, as above, could be to apply Monte-Droput dropout (use dropout at training and leave turned on at inference to estimate variance). However it has been shown that this only models aleatoric uncertainty partially (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04977) and the quality may vary with expressiveness of ur model. If u go further down this road u may also check out this work (https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00598) where the authors introduce error propagation through neural nets to eliminate sampling at inference time. Maybe the error propagation can be of interest to ur specific case.

More importantly however, some works use the entropy of the resulting softmax as an uncertainty estimate. This has been shown to fail for epistemic (model) uncertainty. However, without having a corresponding work on this at hand, I think it will perform decent for the aleatoric uncertainty, which u r trying to model.

What do u need to do? Train ur model on ur noisy dataset and afterwards the entropy of ur softmax should correlate with the aleatoric uncertainty. U can try it by plotting it against classification error.

Best